# TLS over NodeRED Modbus Library available?

Tags: node.js, tcp, tls1.2, node-red, modbus

I have already established connection between PLC and NodeRED via Modbus TCP. I would like to know if there is any option to enable TLS on NodeRED Modbus TCP Library (node-red-contrib-modbus)?

Comment: Modbus is a very simple protocol in no case capable of supporting encryption

Comment: @LluisFelisart there is a [MODBUS Security Protocol](https://modbus.org/docs/MB-TCP-Security-v21_2018-07-24.pdf) that uses TLS.

Answer (score 0):

No - you can see the available config options in [the source](https://github.com/BiancoRoyal/node-red-contrib-modbus/blob/master/src/modbus-server.js#L27).

The [node-red-contrib-modbus](https://flows.nodered.org/node/node-red-contrib-modbus) [server component](https://github.com/BiancoRoyal/node-red-contrib-modbus/blob/master/src/modbus-server.js#L57) uses [jsmodbus](https://www.npmjs.com/package/jsmodbus) which does not appear to [support TLS](https://github.com/Cloud-Automation/node-modbus/issues/277) directly.